# Fastest way to search for longest prefix in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, string-matching

I have a list of phone number prefixes defined for large number of zones (in query defined by gvcode and cgi).
I need to efficiently find a longest prefix that matches given number PHONE_NR.

I use inverted LIKE clause on field digits (which contains prefixes in form +48%, +49%, +1%, +1232% and so on).

Therefore I can't use normal index on that field.

I managed to get substantial improvement by using IOT on gvcode and cgi field (which are part (first two cols) of primary key).
I also looked at some oracle text indexes but can't find one that will match longer input with shorter prefix in the table.

Is there any other way to perform such search that is faster than this approach.

Here is the query which gives a list of all matched prefixes (I sort it afterwards on digits length).

```
  select  t.gvcode,  t.digits
                from NUMBERS t 
                    where 
                        t.gvcode=ZONE_SET_CODE 
                        and t.cgi=cgi_f
                       and ( PHONE_NR like t.digits)
                         order by length(digits) desc
```

Comment: Maybe if you create a function based index on `substr(digits, 2, length(digits)-1)` and then add to your query where clause another condition `and substr(digits, 2, length(digits)-1) <= PHONE_NR` you can see some improvment in some cases

Comment: Should be `and substr(digits, 1, length(digits)-1) <= PHONE_NR` (no need to remove the '+')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the index on "digits" you can create the index on `rpad(substr(digits,1,length(digits)-1), 10, '9')`. "10" is the maximum length that you want to support. You will add an additional condition to the where clause:  `rpad(substr(digits,1,length(digits)-1), 10, '9') >= PHONE_NR`

Your SQL would be:

```
select  t.gvcode,  t.digits
from NUMBERS t 
    where 
        t.gvcode=ZONE_SET_CODE 
        and t.cgi=cgi_f
       and PHONE_NR like t.digits
       and substr(digits, 1, length(digits)-1) <= PHONE_NR
       and rpad(substr(digits,1,length(digits)-1), 10, '9') >= PHONE_NR
order by length(digits) desc
```

Here is an example in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef6fa/5)

Answer (score 1):

I might sound stupid, but when I ran into such problem I went in most non-space-efficient brute force way:

Lets say:

```
L=length of longest prefix to match (without obvious +, of course)
```

Add `L` additional fields naming them, for example, `P1, P2,...,PL`

Update those fields with

```
UPDATE NUMBERS set P1=SUBSTR(PHONE_NR,1,1), P2=SUBSTR(PHONE_NR,1,2), ..., PL=SUBSTR(PHONE_NR,1,L)
```

(in future you can do this in `INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger too)

Now you have L fields to create index on and compare to anything you like.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just writing because I had the same issue. 
If you know the range of the prefix lengths you have, you can do something similar to the following. The following example assumes prefix lengths 2-6

```
select  t.num,  coalesce(p6.PREFIX, p5.PREFIX, p4.PREFIX, p3.PREFIX, p2.PREFIX) PREFIX
  from NUMBERS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN PREFIXES p2 ON substr(t.num,1,2)=p2.PREFIX  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PREFIXES p3 ON substr(t.num,1,3)=p3.PREFIX  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PREFIXES p4 ON substr(t.num,1,4)=p4.PREFIX  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PREFIXES p5 ON substr(t.num,1,5)=p5.PREFIX  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PREFIXES p6 ON substr(t.num,1,6)=p6.PREFIX
```

Equal joins are as good as you can get.

I believe that it runs way better than any other possible solution here, hope it helps anyone who stumbles on the same issue

[Sqlfiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed408/2/0) modified from sailaway's answer whose script still gives all matches instead of only the longest one

Answer (score 1):

I've hit the same problem, I found this solution to be useful (credits to L. Schneider on https://community.oracle.com/thread/351988):

```
create table a (a varchar2(100));
create index a_1 on a(a);

begin
 delete a;
 insert into a values ('00431');
 insert into a values ('004312');
 insert into a values ('0043123');
 insert into a values ('00431234');
 insert into a values ('004312345');
end;
/


select max(a)
  from a 
 where '004311' like a||'%'
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abc975/1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will really help, but I think it's worth a try.

Create a Function Based Index on `substr(digits, 1, length(digits)-1)` (this is just to index digits without the '%')

Then in your query you can add another condition:

```
AND substr(digits, 1, length(digits)-1) <= PHONE_NR
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e48ae/3)

The idea is that with **lexical**  comparison you can "cut out" all the digits which are after PHONE_NR

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Or Replace Function DBA_UTIL.COMMON_PREFIX (P_STRING1 In Varchar2, P_STRING2 In Varchar2)
Return Varchar2
```

As
L_STRING   Varchar2 (100);
Begin
-- ==================================================================================
-- -------   Find any common prefix between 2 strings
-- ==================================================================================

```
With
    FIND_COMMON_PREFIX
    As
        (    Select Max (Rownum)     MAX_PREFIX
               From Dual
              Where Substr (P_STRING1, 1, Rownum) = Substr (P_STRING2, 1, Rownum)
         Connect By Level <= Least (Length (P_STRING1), Length (P_STRING2)))
Select Substr (P_STRING1, 1, MAX_PREFIX)
  Into L_STRING
  From FIND_COMMON_PREFIX;

Return L_STRING;
```

Exception
When Others Then
Return 'BOGUS';
End;
/

Comment: When answering questions, please remember to include an explanation of your answer along with your code.